# Getting pypy to run in uwsgi?

Tags: python, uwsgi

I'm trying to setup uwsgi to use pypy following what is posted here,
using the *build PyPy support as a plugin* method.

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/PyPy.html

I have seemed to manage to *build* the pypy plugin using:

Linux x86 64-bit: http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/pypy/libpypy-c-x86_64_20130524.so

Now I'm running `uwsgi` with this `ini` file below:

```
[uwsgi]
plugins = /home/alphad/uwsgi-2.0/pypy
http = :8080
chdir = /var/www/projecta/src/myproject
pypy-pp = ..
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings
processes = 6
master=true
disable-logging = false
catch-exceptions = false
post-buffering = 8192
vacuum = true
listen = 120
pypy-home = /home/alphad/pypy-2.2.1-linux64/
pypy-lib = /home/alphad/pypy-2.2.1-linux64/lib_pypy/libpypy-c.so
pypy-wsgi-file = myproject/apache/django.wsgi
```

It seems to be detecting pypy, but also it's trying to use python, so it stops/crashes with the following error:

> !!! Loading both PyPy and CPython in the same process IS PURE EVIL AND
>   IT IS NOT SUPPORTED !!!

How can I get uwsgi to properly run using PYPY?  *I'm not trying to be evil...*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebuild your uWSGI server without the python plugin embedded.

make PROFILE=nolang

will do the trick